passport login issues in session
I'm having trouble with my passport. The login process went through without any issues, but the passport key has to be saved into the session and there is not req.user in the requset

the initapp function for setting some config

export default function initExpress(express, app) {
    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(cors());
    setDbSessions(app, process.env.DB_URL); // setting some config for db

  // maddleware for debugging
  app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log(" ----------------------------------- ");
    console.log('Session:', req.session);
    console.log(" ----------------------------------- ");
    next();
  });

    app.get("/welcome", isAuth, (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.session);
        res.send("<h1> welcome boss </h1>");
    });

    app.post("/pass-login", passport.authenticate("local"), (req, res) => {
        console.log(req.session);
        res.send("<h1> welcome from auth password login </h1>");
    });
}



function for setting db and session
function setDbSessions(app, url) {
  mongoose.connect(url,{}).catch(error => console.log("App.js mongoose.connect error",error));
  let db = mongoose.connection;
  db.on('error', console.error);
  db.once('open', function(){
    console.log("App is connected to DB", db.name)
  });

  app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: MongoStore.create({
      client: mongoose.connection.getClient() 
    }),
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 
    },
  }));
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
    passport.use(localStratage);
}



passport strategy file
import { Strategy } from "passport-local";
import { comparePassword } from "./bcrypt.mjs";
import { User } from "../dbScheme/UserScheme.mjs";
import passport from "passport";

const customFields = {
  username: 'username',
  password: 'password',
};

const checkValidFields = (username, password, done) => {
  User.findOne({ username: username })
    .then((user) => {
      if (!user) return done(null, false); 
      const match = comparePassword(password, user.password);
      if (match) {
        return done(null, user);
      }else {
        return done(null, false);
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => { 
      console.log(err);
      done(err); 
    });
};

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((userId, done) => {
  User.findById(userId)
    .then((user) => {
      done(null, user);
    })
    .catch(err => done(err))
});

const localStratage = new Strategy(customFields, checkValidFields);
export default localStratage;



isAuth function for check for auth user
export const isAuth = (req, res, done) => {
  console.log(req.session);
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        done();
    } else {
        res.status(404).send("<h1> not authorzation user </h1>");
    }
};

and if i visited /welcome end ponit after i login in show me
not authorzation user

this output object come pass-login end point
Session {
  cookie: {
    path: '/',
    _expires: 2024-07-14T11:27:14.100Z,
    originalMaxAge: 86400000,
    httpOnly: true
  },
  passport: { user: '66925ade46279d6d21a6491e' }
}

this output object come from the middle ware for debugging
Session {
  cookie: {
    path: '/',
    _expires: 2024-07-14T11:36:32.934Z,
    originalMaxAge: 86400000,
    httpOnly: true
  }
}

so how to make the passport key attach to the session object in request and why this issue happens ??

Please see if there is a middleware loaded in the server to parse the incoming cookie. cookie-parser is one of it, used for it.

i try it but don't work too give the same not authorzation user after i login in

Hi, Thank you for the update and sorry for my incorrect comment. As you know, there is a session cookie created during welcome, and it is sent to the browser for subsequent request. Therefore please check in Browser Developer tools/Application/Storage/Cookies that there is a session cookie stored after welcome. This is the first point to check. Please also ensure that the welcome request from the client should include the option credentials: include, otherwise this cookie will not be stored in browser.

Please refer to this post for more: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78696903/unable-to-access-authorisation-cookie/78710407#78710407

I slove the probelm thanks

Hi, If possible, please share with us the fix worked for you.

restart the server
